# Fusion gantt chart not plotting dates while using custom function for labels

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

Hi I want to display `json` values as my gantt chart labels. So, I have tried something like this

```
"processes": {
    "headertext": "Task",
    "align": "left",
    "process": processLabels 
  }
```

The processLabels has the function that returns some set of array values. The simple function is below

```
function genChart() {
    var milestones = ["task1","task2","task3"];
    var processLabels = [] 
    for (var i=0;i<=2;i++) {
        processLabels.push({
            "label":  '"'+milestones[i]+'"'  ,
        "id": '"'+i+'"'
        });

    }
    return processLabels;
}
```

The problem is I'm getting only the labels and the dates are not plotted [image]

Here is my full code :

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>My first chart using FusionCharts Suite XT</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Step 1 - Including the fusioncharts core library -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src=" http://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script> 
        <!-- Step 2 - Including the fusion theme -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src=" http://cdn.fusioncharts.com/fusioncharts/latest/fusioncharts.theme.fusion.js"></script> 
      <script>
      var processLabels = genChart();
      const dataSource = {
      "chart": {
        "dateformat": "dd/mm/yyyy",
        "caption": "Planned vs Actual",
        "subcaption": "For BigHead v3",
        "plottooltext": "<b>$label</b><br>Start: <b>$start</b><br>End: <b>$end</b>",
        "theme": "fusion"
      },
      "legend": {
        "item": [
          {
            "label": "Planned",
            "color": "#0000AA"
          },
          {
            "label": "Actual",
            "color": "#88D8B0"
          },
          {
            "label": "Slack (Delay)",
            "color": "#e44a00"
          }
        ]
      },
      "tasks": {
        "task": [
          {
            "label": "Planned",
            "processid": "1",
            "start": "5/4/2018",
            "end": "12/4/2018",
            "id": "1-1",
            "color": "#0000AA",
            "alpha": "100",
            "height": "27%",
            "toppadding": "32%"
          },
          {
            "label": "Actual",
            "processid": "1",
            "start": "10/4/2018",
            "end": "29/4/2018",
            "id": "1",
            "color": "#88D8B0",
            "alpha": "100",
            "height": "27%",
            "toppadding": "65%"
          },
          {
            "label": "Planned",
            "processid": "2",
            "start": "10/4/2018",
            "end": "20/4/2018",
            "id": "2-1",
            "color": "#0000AA",
            "alpha": "100",
            "height": "27%",
            "toppadding": "32%"
          },
          {
            "label": "Actual",
            "processid": "2",
            "start": "10/4/2018",
            "end": "22/4/2018",
            "id": "2",
            "color": "#88D8B0",
            "alpha": "100",
            "height": "27%",
            "toppadding": "65%"
          },
          {
            "label": "Planned",
            "processid": "3",
            "start": "21/4/2018",
            "end": "30/4/2018",
            "id": "3-1",
            "color": "#0000AA",
            "alpha": "100",
            "height": "27%",
            "toppadding": "32%"
          },
          {
            "label": "Actual",
            "processid": "3",
            "start": "22/4/2018",
            "end": "1/5/2018",
            "id": "3",
            "color": "#88D8B0",
            "alpha": "100",
            "height": "27%",
            "toppadding": "65%"
          }
        ]
      },
      "processes": {
        "headertext": "Task",
        "align": "left",
        "process": processLabels 
      },
      "categories": [
        {
          "category": [
            {
              "start": "01/04/2018",
              "end": "30/04/2018",
              "label": "April"
            },
            {
              "start": "01/05/2018",
              "end": "31/05/2018",
              "label": "May"
            },
            {
              "start": "1/6/2018",
              "end": "30/6/2018",
              "label": "June"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "category": [

          ]
        }
      ]
    };

    FusionCharts.ready(function() {
       var myChart = new FusionCharts({
          type: "gantt",
          renderAt: "chart-container",
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          dataFormat: "json",
          dataSource
       }).render();
    });

    function genChart() {
        var milestones = ["task1","task2","task3"];
        var processLabels = [] 
        for (var i=0;i<=2;i++) {
            processLabels.push({
                "label":  '"'+milestones[i]+'"'  ,
            "id": '"'+i+'"'
            });

        }
        return processLabels;
    }
      </script>
      <body>
      <div id="chart-container"></div>
      </body>
    </head>
    </html>
```

Please let me know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting the taskbar because of the processLabels array which you are generating is creating the labels and id object values incorrectly please remove the blank quotes from the object to make it work, here is the updated implementation

```
function genChart() {
    var milestones = ["task1", "task2", "task3"];
    var processLabels = []
    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
      processLabels.push({
        "label": '' + milestones[i] + '',
        "id": '' + i + ''
      });

    }
    return processLabels;
  }
```

Refer this fiddle for further - http://jsfiddle.net/Lstj92rh/

Comment: Can you please do me a favor? how can i remove the grid lines in that chart

Comment: set "gridborderalpha":"0",
      "ganttLineAlpha":"0" at the chart object level